# WP Mail SMTP with Gmail constantly disconnects. How to automate checking that connection is alive

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, smtp, gmail

I've using WP Mail SMTP with Gmail on several sites.  It used to work well enough but now it constantly stops sending emails.  The solution is to "Remove Connection" via the Wordpress->WP Mail STMTP-> Settings page, then re-add the connection.

I've followed their instructions to the letter:
https://wpmailsmtp.com/docs/how-to-set-up-the-gmail-mailer-in-wp-mail-smtp/

On the Wordpress support forum for the plugin they suggest that running the Goole App inTesting Mode can cause issues of disconnects but I've been run "in production" and the issues still persist.

Does anybody have any suggestions for how to automate a test for this so that I can be notified with the connection breaks and I need to reconnect the gmail account?  It would simply need to test the contact app periodically and upon fail, send an email notification.

Plugin stopps sending email via Gmail constantly and needs to be reconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [UpTimeRobot.com](https://uptimerobot.com/) can monitor and give you notifications on Email Servers, Heartbeat Monitors, HTTP monitors, SSL, and more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).